# Extract value from Json string in SQL Server

Tags: json

How can I extract data from this Json column without using a big function ,just using simple query

I want to extract value "Hospitality" from mypropertytype

Example:

```
[{"myPropertyType":{"code":"9","name":"Hospitality"},"myPropertySubType":{"code":"901","name":"Hotel"},"yourPropertyType":{"code":"9","name":"Hospitality"},"yourPropertySubType":{"code":"901","name":"Hotel"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the package `Newtonsoft.Json` you can deserialize any JSON into a class.

```
class MyPropertyType {
  int code { get; set; }
  string name { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyPropertyType>>(sqlJsonString);
```